# How to remove up to a certain punctuation when there are same punctuations

Tags: r, regex

I have a dataframe with 1 column called filepath which contains file path:

```
filepath
C:\Windows\App\app1.exe
C:\Windows\App\folder1\app1.exe
```

I need to split up to the last backslash, and the exe file will be in another column. How should I split the directory path?

Below is the snapshot of the result I need to obtain.
[image: newdata]

I have tried regex expressions to obtain filepath1, eg:

```
df$filepath1 <- gsub("\\\\.*","",df$filepath)
```

but it doesnt work, because it will remove everything after the first match, and returning `C:` .

Comment: You need `gsub("[^\\\\]+$", "", x)`

Comment: I guess you need the regex `(.*\\)[^\\]*$` and have to use the first matching group! :)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks! it works. :)

Comment: @csabinho, yours didnt work tho. But still thanks!

Comment: see ?`basename` and `dirname`